# The branch is not showing as a separate branch

Tags: git, graph

Why can't I see my recently modified branch as a separate line in the graph?

[image: Terminal output]

Answer (score 1):

Git only creates a ‘fork’ in the graph when there’s two lines that need drawing in parallel.

You can consider Git’s graph as drawing the commits first, then decorating the commits with branch names.

Looking purely at the commits and their hierarchy, there are three commits in a line.

```
*
*
*
```

Decorating these commits with branch names gives you

```
* (documentation)
* (master)
*
```

There’s nothing more that needs to be or should be done.

If you had two commits with the same parent, Git would need to create a fork in the graph to be able to graph the commits. This is still ignoring branches.

```
*
| *
|/
*
*
```

Then the graph is decorated with branch names. Branches don’t change commit hierarchy or the graph itself since they’re just pointers to existing commits on an existing graph, so creating or removing branches doesn’t change the graph itself.